# Create and position divs relative to parent

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create(and position) rectangle divs on a parent div. The created div should be positioned relative. Here is a working **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4z7sf5c/2/)** example -> Just draw some rectangles by holding mouse button.

```js
var newRect = null;
 var offset = $('#page').offset();
 
function point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
 
function rect(firstPoint) {
  this.firstPoint = firstPoint;
  this.div = document.createElement("div");
  this.div.style.position = "relative";
  this.div.style.border = "solid 1px grey";
  this.div.style.top = this.firstPoint.y+"px";
  this.div.style.left = this.firstPoint.x+"px";
  this.div.style.width = "0px";
  this.div.style.height = "0px";
  $("#page").append(this.div);
}


$("#page").mousedown(function (e) {
  if(e.which == 1) {
    var x = e.pageX - offset.left;
    var y = e.pageY - offset.top;
    newRect = new rect(new point(x, y));
  }
});
    
$("#page").mousemove(function (e) {
  if(newRect) {
    newRect.div.style.width = Math.abs(newRect.firstPoint.x-(e.pageX - offset.left))+"px";
    newRect.div.style.height = Math.abs(newRect.firstPoint.y-(e.pageY - offset.top))+"px";
  }
});
    
$("#page").mouseup(function (e) {
  if(e.which == 1 && newRect != null) {
    if(Math.abs(newRect.firstPoint.x-(e.pageX - offset.left)) < 10) {
      $("#"+newRect.div.id).remove();
      newRect = null;
      return;
    }

    $("#"+newRect.div.id).on('mousedown', function (e) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

    newRect = null;
  }
});
```

```css
#page{
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
    border:solid 2px #6D6D6D;
    cursor: crosshair;
    background-color: white;
    float:left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
</div>
```

After drawing the first rectangle, which is positioned correctly, each rectangle is positioned false. I think that there is something wrong with the calculation of the position... maybe someone can give me a hint.

Comment: Welcome, @0bmis. You may have better success getting help over at the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) StackExchange site. Code Review is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code.

Comment: @gfullam Code Review requires code that is working as intended already. This code has problems as stated by the author and would be off-topic on Code Review. See [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @Phrancis Ha! You're right, and that meta post exactly describes what I just did. :) Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change 
  `this.div.style.position = "relative";`

to
 `this.div.style.position = "absolute";`

Bonus: Here's a version that allows you to draw in any direction: https://jsfiddle.net/g4z7sf5c/5/

I simply added this code to the `mousemove` function:

```
if (e.pageX < newRect.firstPoint.x) {
    newRect.div.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
}
if (e.pageY < newRect.firstPoint.y) {
    newRect.div.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
}
```

Comment: I need that the divs are positioned relative to the parent div.

Comment: @0bmis Explain why or give us a scenario and maybe we can find a workaround.

Comment: Is this what you had in mind?  https://jsfiddle.net/g4z7sf5c/4/  This shows a drawing surface that isn't the full size of the page.

Comment: Added a version that lets you draw in any direction, not just top-left to bottom-right.

Comment: @Aprillion I need that because the parent div and the rectangle divs are translated to XSL(for pdf conversion) and here i need the relative position of the rectangle divs.

Comment: Have you considered using HTML5 canvas and exporting the SVG instead?

Comment: Yes, but i wan't to support not HTML5 capable browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately not. But i understand now why the style tag position:relative is the problem. What i try to accomplish is that when i set the top style of the rectangles to 0 they should be at the top of the parent div. Like here in this [image](http://postimg.org/image/3xmvzgsdz/). Its possible to do it with css?

Comment: Okay I'm trying a crazy solution where I keep track of the height of the last rectangle and then offset the next one with a negative value: https://jsfiddle.net/g4z7sf5c/6/  It's still a WIP but it's kind of working...

Comment: @0bmis what is stopping you to give the parent div `position: relative` in order for the absolute position of the rectangles to be calculated as offset from the parent?

Comment: @Aprillion Thank you, that is it!

Comment: Oh, I thought that's the way it *was* behaving.  Glad you got it figured out though!